# About AngularJS performance with large application specifically an ERP application

Tags: angularjs, erp

Our team want to choose a technical architecture for our future ERP web application. We have fixed the choice for the back-end layer, actually we'll use Spring Data JPA/Hibernate and CXF web service to develop the service layer.

Right now we're a little confused about the font-end framework to use so as to develop the client layer. Can anyone give me his viewpoint about AngularsJS framework, is it possible use it to develop all the front-end layer including soap and rest web service calls? Will it fit with our ERP application? I mean from a **performance** standpoint? because there is a lot of data that will be saved in the client side? Working with **Javascript** in the client layer? Doesn't it **slow down** the treatment inside the application?

Comment: Yes, angular is just javascript, so.... you can pretty much do anything that any other javascript framework could do. Performance-wise, that is also not a problem, as long as you understand how to write code in such a way that it performs well. Performance problems are usually due to logic problems/developer error, not the framework being used (or maybe browser if you're allowing really old IE).

Comment: Thank you for you response, even if we use js for all the whole client layer ? I mean webservice  calls, XML/Json parsing, object binding (between back-end layer and front-end layer), it will not reveal a performance problems ? what's is better ?, use java classes for the binding of the object or use javascript ?

Comment: Yes, the client can handle all of that. Which one is better depends on too many factors to answer here on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey we are developing a hybrid application for data logistics which is connected through webservices and a Database with the ERP System.

We are using angularJs / Ionic Framework / Cordova 
For saving data on the ClientSide we decided to use Localstorage / our own setter/getter Service and WebSql since we are doing offline Functionality too.

Our app is growing big and we have no Performance issues what so ever currently we have about 80 different views.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you bro for your prompt response, what if we make all webservice calls in java classes and then use POJOs to feed the angularjs model? does it comply with angula js MVC design pattern ? or we have to do that from js side ? because I think that java is more efficient than js ?

Comment: Well we have some asp.net Webservices all we do is make $http post / get requests to send out data and the WebService is writing the data in to our DB from there if some specific Status is reached, a stored Procedure is sending the data to the erp system. So basicly we collect data on our angular / ionic / cordova client send em via asp.net WebServices to our DB and from there to the erp System. And ofc u can do ur Webservice calls in java why not. I dont know what POJOs are but we are feeding our angular model through a success callback from out $http request